# Will Apache Commons work in all servers?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

Will the Apache commons files(jar) work in all servers or only in the Apache server?

Comment: the only possible problem is that the server itself may use that jar, and perhaps use a different version than you do. If that is the case, and you run into version incompatibility problems,  you will need to specify that the server's class loader should use parent-last loading. This is unlikely though in this case.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy All app servers I've ever worked with load from the application classpath before the server classpath - are there any that do parent-first by default? This sounds like it would be quite a pain in the butt

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: How i know the server was already having the jar?? Is any way to check that??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apache commons is simply a library of useful java classes. All you need is only the appropriate JRE.

Answer (score 1):

They'll work in any environment that supports their language level.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,Apache Common Files is work in all server.It will support all server..